# Tool for multiplying really big numbers

Tags: python

**I write a program for multiplying really big numbers.**
Lets say I have two numbers: first with 532 digits, second with 526 digits.
My program gives me a number, that look quite right: it has 1058 digits.

I tried to compare the result with some tool to check if my program calculates it right.
I used python: for these input numbers, it looks correct. First digits are the same, last digits are the same. I can't compare every digits cause there are over thousand now.
Also I want to check my program for bigger input numbers.

So, to finally verify the result I type in python:

```
first_number * second_number - my_program_result
```

For numbers with ~ <200 digits result is 0. For bigger numbers I got:

```
-1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000L
```

**I dont know is it my programs fault or pythons.
Can python handle such big numbers?
 Is there any other tool I can use to verify my results?**

**EDIT**
As asked, I give numbers that gave me that output:

```
3475674888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666699999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999933333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333366666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666662222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222288888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888882222222222222222222222222

3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333377777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777778888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222299999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999
```

Comment: Could you do it with sage?

Comment: Post the numbers that gave you that output.

Comment: Using Python to compare two 1000-character strings should be trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Python's built-in function `cmp()` to compare the product of your multiplied numbers to your expected result.

```
>>> print cmp(product_of_multiplication, expected_result)
```

If `product_of_multiplication == expected_result`, then `0` will be returned.

If `product_of_multiplication > expected_result`, then `1` will be returned.

If `product_of_multiplication < expected_result`, the `-1` will be returned.

Comment: Thank you, I tried it as:
x = <first number> * <second number>
print cmp(x, <my resuly>)

I get: -1.
I will try to check my program for another values on another machine.